# changing image while installation using WIX

Tags: wix, wix3.5

I am using WIX 3.5 to build my installer.
I Want to show one image while current feature is being installed and other image once that feature installation is completed.

[image]

I am using BillBoard and the code snippets is :`<BillboardAction Id="InstallFiles">

                <Billboard Id="BB1" Feature="ProductFeature">
                    <Control Id="Bitmap" Type="Bitmap" X="0" Y="0" FixedSize="yes" Width="20" Height="17" Text="Image8" />
                </Billboard>

            </BillboardAction>`
The problem is that if i am using several images then its keeps on showing images repeatedly over the period of **InstallFiles** custom action. I Have two feature and i want to show one image while installing a particular feature and once installation of that feature gets completed i want to show another image. I want to perform this action for both the features.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Billboards can't be used like that. Features control what happens during actions like InstallFiles but each action runs only once, regardless of which features are selected.